# Freeform to show via Vue Js

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce, plugin-freeform, vue

I have 3 freeforms - form 1, form 2 and form 3. I want a select option on which I click and the necessary form opens as per the selection.

Can I render the Freeform which are build using VUE js Select method?

If so how? Because when I try to render Craft.Freeform it shows me this error

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you're running into a collision with Vue's template delimiters vs Twig's, which by default are the same as each other (`{{ ... }}`). The solution is to change Vue's delimiters to something else when you initialise, like this:

```
const vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    delimiters: ['${', '}'],
    ...
    ...
});
```

You'd then need to use `${ ... }` as your Vue delimiters.